# asp hide radiobutton label

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css

I'm having trouble hiding the text on a radio button. Here's asp for the radios...

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="rdViewPrint" Text="View/Print" runat="server" OnClick="javascript:disableFields();" GroupName="viewSend" Checked="True" style="margin-left:10px;" />
<asp:RadioButton ID="rdEmail" Text="Email" runat="server" OnClick="javascript:emailFields();" GroupName="viewSend" style="margin-left:10px;" />
<asp:RadioButton ID="rdFax" Text="Fax" runat="server" OnClick="javascript:faxFields();" GroupName="viewSend" style="margin-left:10px;" />
```

on page load, a javascript function runs the function below. The cirles of the radio buttons are hidden, but the text remains.

```
function noVisit() {
     document.getElementById('<%=lblViewSend.ClientID%>').style.display = "none";
     document.getElementById('<%=rdViewPrint.ClientID%>').style.display = "none";
     document.getElementById('<%=rdEmail.ClientID%>').style.display = "none";
     document.getElementById('<%=rdFax.ClientID%>').style.display = "none";
     document.getElementById('<%=btnFull.ClientID%>').style.display = "none";
     document.getElementById('<%=btnSummary.ClientID%>').style.display = "none";
     document.getElementById('<%=btnPrivate.ClientID%>').style.display = "none";
}
```

Why does the text not get hidden, and how do I make it not visible?

Thanks, Dave K.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy fix for this would be to just put the whole thing in a panel and then hide that.  Or is there a reason you could not do that?

Comment: Thank for the idea. Still pretty new at asp, didn't even think about that.

Comment: Generally for hiding or showing panels are a great idea.  Unless you are doing it for a single element, then hiding/showing that element is the better option.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the HTML generated by ASP.NET on your page. I think you'll find that LABEL tags are emitted for the text of the radio buttons. Your Javascript is not targetting the LABEL's - you're targetting the INPUT's.

Another suggestion - toggle classes to show/hide them. Much easier to keep track of and allows you consolidate other styling goodness with CSS.

Comment: you were absolutely right about the text being as a label. Placed the radios in a panel as @Chris suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
rdViewPrint.Visible = false;
rdEmail.Visible = false;
rdFax.Visible = false;
```